# How to get a single child from firebase database

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have checked high and low but all I see are people trying to to get all the children into lists and stuff. I just want to get a single child from the database.

```
{
  "Haydn" : {
    "Users" : {
      "email" : "user@gmail.com",
      "name" : "kofi"
    }
  }
}
```

**I want to get the name from the structure.**

My code:

```
        rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = rootNode.getReference().child("Users");

        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if(snapshot.exists()){
                            String displayName = (String) snapshot.child("Haydn").child("Users").child("name").getValue();
                            loggedInUserTextView.setText(displayName);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                }
```

Comment: 1) Instead of showing a schematic representation, can you show us the actual JSON at `/Users` (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) Can you then indicate what value from this JSON you want to show in `loggedInUserTextView`?

Comment: updated it with the stuff

Comment: 1) What is the `"Haydn"` in your question meant to represent in the JSON? 2) I **highly** recommend exporting the data, instead of typing it out, as `AppName` is also not normally part of the exported JSON (although it is part of the URL to the database). If you have sensitive data in the JSON, you can change it. But don't change the structure, as it's impossible to help you without seeing the actual JSON.

Comment: There is no sensitive information. I just thought it will make much more sense. Haydn == AppName. Sorry about that

Comment: Please post database picture instead of structure.

Comment: @Ashish For the Firebase Realtime Database it's far better to include the structure as text instead of a picture. That way if we need to use in in an answer it can be copy and pasted (so we don't have to retype the while thing). As long as the data is exported and pasted as Frank mentioned in his comment, we are good to go.

Comment: @Rabbid76 well I got down voted so I thought the question was not informative enough

Comment: @Rabbid76 I will repost it now

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have reposted it now. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up your reference like this:

```
reference = rootNode.getReference().child("Users");
```

That means that Firebase reads the data from `/Users` in your database. Since there is no `Users` node at the root of the JSON you posted, that means the `snapshot` you get is going to be empty.

---

To read a single node, as you're trying to do here, set up a reference to the exact path of that node:

```
reference = rootNode.getReference().child("Haydn/Users/name");
```

As you can see, you can pass the entire path to the node in the `child(...)`.

With this reference, you can then read the value like this:

```
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            String displayName = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            loggedInUserTextView.setText(displayName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException();
    }
}
```